# How to efficiently integrate this function?

Tags: r, double, integration

I have written this R code to double integrate a function (where a boundary is infinite):

```
nom <- function(u){
  tau <- 90   
  r <- 0   
  alpha <- .2
  k <- 1
  f1 <- function(c){(tau-u)*(alpha*k^alpha)^2/(k+c)^(alpha+1)*
                      (1/(k+r*tau+u+c)^(alpha+1)+
                       1/(k+r*tau-u+c)^(alpha+1))}
  integrate(f1,lower=0,upper=Inf)$value }
D <- Vectorize(nom)
q1 <- integrate(D,lower=0,upper=tau)
```

I obtained the following message

```
Error in integrate(f1, lower = 0, upper = Inf) : 
  non-finite function value
```

I have remarked that when changing r above the 0 value there will be no problem. But my task consists of choosing r to be exactly zero.
Please can any one help to integrate this function with r=0.

Comment: If i run your example as shown then R issues an error message  `object tau not found`.  After moving `tau` to outside the function, and experimenting with values for `r > 0`, the `non-finite function value` error is still issued. You need to give more information.

Comment: tau is an input to the code, it is given in the second line tau<-90.

Comment: Yes I can see that. It is also being used at toplevel in the call of `integrate` on the last line of your example. It is not available there i.e. you have not defined `tau` at toplevel.

Comment: I realized what did you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to integrate numerically a function which, for `r=0`, diverges strongly at `c=u-k` and at `c=-u-k`. This won't work. I suggest that you try to change the parameters and/or integration range; or that you search in mathematical textbooks for an analytical solution (if it exists).

```
tau <- 90   
r <- 0   
alpha <- .2
k <- 1
u<-1 # I set this parameter to 1, the value is not decisive for the problem
f1 <- function(c){(tau-u)*(alpha*k^alpha)^2/(k+c)^(alpha+1)*
      (1/(k+r*tau+u+c)^(alpha+1)+
         1/(k+r*tau-u+c)^(alpha+1))}
plot(f1, xlab="c")
```

[image]

PS: According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) your integral does not coverge for `r=0`. In other words, it seems that there is no solution other than "infinity" in this case. 
[image]

Comment: Here the integration is in two dimensions, I integrate first with respect to c and then with respect to u. according to some scientific papers there exists no analytical form to that double integration, for that reason I have tried to use numerical integration

Comment: I understand that this is different. Still your integrand will contain a singularity, and I'm not sure if a meaningful numerical integration is possible in such a case.

Comment: Is it possible here to do some change of variables, or some mathematical trics, to overcome that problem? thank you.